# Static Array values Working But Dynamic Not Working

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending some check box values using ajax request.with the name if "id".This is one Part of the CSV File Generator.

```
$pid=$_POST['id'];
$idarray1=array();
$idarray1  = explode(",",$pid);
foreach($idarray as $jesarray){
    printf( "SELECT * FROM clents where clientid='".$jesarray."'");
}
```

This code showing sql query with clientid empty..

But when I put static values

```
$idarray1=array(36,37);
foreach($idarray as $jesarray){
    printf( "SELECT * FROM clents where clientid='".$jesarray."'");
}
```

It is working perfect .

Can You guys help me where I was wrong..

Comment: value of $_POST['id'] ?

Comment: Yes it is coming I checked in alert...36,37

Comment: In database you are storing clientid in comma separated?

Comment: Use `IN` here, `'SELECT * FROM clents where clientid IN ($jesarray)'`, Where `$jesarray` is string like "37,36".

Comment: put foreach($idarray1 as $jesarray){ instead foreach($idarray as $jesarray){

Comment: Right Now I checked Static $pid="36,37"; working,Do you think the problem with post values..

Comment: var checkedValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
I am retriving clientid in this method And When I alert it shows 35,36,38..

Comment: Have you debugged the value of $pid? Another thing to note is that you're not escaping user input before putting it into an SQL query so your code is open to SQL injection once you run the queries. Another thing to note is the second example won't work as the variable $idarray doesn't exist.

Comment: First of all You have typo in variable namse:
`$idarray1` and `$idarray`. Next show us what is output from `var_dump($idarray1)` after explode.

Answer (score 0):

It is beacuse a syntax error in your foreach vars.

You put **$idarray** instead of **$idarray1**:

Change

```
foreach($idarray as $jesarray){
    printf( "SELECT * FROM clents where clientid='".$jesarray."'");
}
```

to

```
foreach($idarray1 as $jesarray){
    printf( "SELECT * FROM clents where clientid='".$jesarray."'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a foreach loop here for this kind of values, Simply go with `IN`. Make it simple, No array.

```
$pid = $_POST['id']; //36,37
printf('SELECT * FROM clents where clientid IN ($pid)');
```